# Displaying an SVF model in a browser

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation

Use Design Automation API to convert SVF,
I was able to get it to the OSS bucket as output.zip.

Continue using the token and documentId, like the attached HTML that can be executed currently.
I would like to view the model in a browser.
In addition, since the number of trials is large, I would like to do this without using the ModeDerivative API.

```js
function initializeViewer() {
  const options = {
    env: "AutodeskProduction",
    api: "derivativeV2",
    accessToken: token,
  };

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
      document.getElementById("MyViewerDiv")
    );
    viewer.start();
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      `urn:${documentId}`,
      function (doc) {
        const defaultModel = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, defaultModel);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

As documentId, `documentId=base64Encode("urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/output.zip")`

I tried that, but it didn't work.
Does anything else need to be done?

Comment: I do not think `.zip` package should work.

Added `autodesk-viewer` tag. Viewer experts can respond.

Answer (score 1):

We are doing exactly this. We do SVF export using Inventor engine on FDA. That produces zip. Such a zip needs to be moved to the webserver and unarchived there to individual files so they can be server across the http to browser as forge viewer is serving them individually. You can see the setup here https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/ClientApp/src/components/forgeView.js

application using it https://inventor-config-demo.autodesk.io/

Comment: I looked at the following to see how to set it up.
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/ClientApp/src/components/forgeView.js
I'm sorry, but I don't know how to use this file.
Can I use forgeViewer.js to create a web page that displays an unzipped SVF file in 3D?
I installed Create React App and tried using forgeViewer.js. However, an additional import is required in forgeViewer.js. Are these collected manually as scripts or css? Some items may not be found among the import destinations.

Answer (score 1):

To make viewer point to local SVF files (or self-hosted files), use this example:

https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/310bf82d32e3dca2647f66ec84ff4e08#file-index-html

basically point the Viewer to the `.svf` file, like this:

```
options = {
    env: "Local",
    isAEC: true,
    urn: "offline-svfs/1/svf/2021.svf"
};
viewer.start(options.urn, options);
```

Comment: I'm also build a repo sample apply both local and online, hope can help more information for question, because also need require detail of file svf inside to load : https://github.com/chuongmep/svf-viewer/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I learned from GitHUb below that we can display an svf file by specifying it as a document.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample
We are able to display the svf, by specifying it in the html using the URL of the document through localhost.

```
var options = {
          'env' : 'Local',
          'document' : './shaver/0.svf'
      };
```

In the future, I would like to be able to display it from a cloud server instead of localhost.
However, I will end this issue here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).